# Error Getting Geoposition from Browser using Angular Dart

Tags: web, geolocation, dart, angular-dart

I have a question regarding  getting a users location and an error bubbling up:

I am using this to get the user's location

```
  @override
  ngOnInit() {
    window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition().listen((position) => userPosition = position);
  }
```

This does prompt the browser to ask for permission to share the user's location, however, it also produces an error, and the position doesn't appear to get set:

```
html_dart2js.dart:3558 EXCEPTION: Instance of 'PositionError'
STACKTRACE: 
null
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Instance of 'PositionError'
```

I was wondering if I am doing this wrong?

Comment: Is this only in Dartium, or also in Chrome?

Comment: Oh @GünterZöchbauer, you so smart. :-) Dartium error, indeed!

Comment: You could try the devcompiler. If it works already for your project, you might get a better developer experience https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartdevc

Answer (score 1):

In case you still need help, I was facing the same problem and came to this solution by inspecting the `listen` function:

```
window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition().listen((
          Geoposition newPosition) {
        //handle your position here
      }, onError: (Error e){
        // handle your error here
      });
```

Hope this helps, keep up the good work!